# Shrink Flex in CSS does not shrink at max level

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to shrink my div element at its maximum level.But at some point it does shrink and overflow from the container.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container {
  min-height: 400px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-inline: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-content: space-evenly;
}

.box {
  /* min-width:100px; */
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 50px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello Flex</h1>
<main class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
</main>
```

Please guide me how can I resolve this issue that at extreme minimum position my div elements did not overflow from my container.

I've attached the image of my result at extreme minimum position my div element overflow from the container.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGhDV.jpg)

Comment: It overflows because you've got a constant number for gap and font size and it physically can't shrink down any further. Look at using clamp or if you need to preserve these values just add overflow:hidden to your container class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

```css
@media (max-width: 300px) {
  .container {
    overflow: auto;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
}
```